# Jenkins User Acceptance step in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, build-pipeline-plugin

I have a project & pipeline set up within my jenkins instance which looks like this.
[image]

This can be described as;

- `[Project]` - Build the project
- `[Project Deploy Test]` - Deploys the project to a test server
- `[Project UA Test]` - The User Acceptance step, where the user must manually test and accept
- `[Project Deploy Prod]` - Once the user has accepted the UA Test the build is deployed to production

---

All steps are working well, except the `[Project UA Test]` step.
This step should just be a button or something which the user can manually trigger once he or she is happy with the build.

The question is, **How can I configure this step to enforce some user interaction (like clicking a button) before proceeding to the next step?**

---

I have tried making the build parametrised with a Choice Parameter, but I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing.

[image]

Comment: I am willing to use plugins if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Promoted Builds Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin

You can use the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) which has a manual promotion workflow.

You could have:

1. `[Project]` --> `[Project Deploy Test]` --> `[Project UA Test]`
2. `[Project UA Test]` --(manual promotion)--> `[Project Deploy Prod]`

Explanation: business as usual until the user acceptance tests are complete. When complete, you can do the manual promotion process. The promotion process can be configured to kick off a downstream build; so in effect your pipeline resume.

### Delivery Pipeline Plugin

(note: I haven't played with this plugin, so I'm just guessing)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin

The [Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) lets you configure a job to have a postbuild action, which is a manual trigger, and lets you resume your pipeline.

### Write your own?

Conceptually, to break your pipeline and have a user "confirm" a build is good, the build needs to provide an action that can be performed after the build is complete.  E.g.

- `KeepBuildForEverAction` (keep build forever)
- `ClaimBuildAction` (claim plugin)

Answer (score 1):

The [Workflow plugin suite](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) supports this use case via an `input` step.